# UICollectionView handle selection with NSIndexPath

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

I'm using a collection view in my app with the selection of cells ..

To handle the selection I am using an `NSIndexPath` that I call in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and in `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`.

The selection seems to work fine but when I select two cells nearby it seems that the `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` is not called ... where am I doing wrong?

this is my code

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *selectedIndex;

@implementation YearSelector

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    YearCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:yearCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.yearLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.yearArray[indexPath.item]];

    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectedIndex]) [cell highlightedYear:YES];
    else [cell highlightedYear:NO];


    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSIndexPath *newIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.item inSection:0];
    [collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:newIndex atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];

    YearCell *cell = (YearCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    _selectedIndex =  indexPath;
    [cell highlightedYear:YES];
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YearCell *cell = (YearCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell highlightedYear:NO];

    _selectedIndex = nil;
}
```

This is the code I use for highlighted cell ( Custom Year Cell)

```
-(void)highlightedYear:(BOOL)highlighted {
    if (highlighted) {
        _baseView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#FF7751" setAlpha:1];
        _baseView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor;
        _yearLabel.textColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor;
    }

    else {
        _baseView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#272D3D" setAlpha:1];
        _baseView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#485674" setAlpha:1].CGColor;
        _yearLabel.textColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not a straight answer, but a suggestion. You could simplify things a bit by using existing apis for this. For enforcing a singular selection there is `allowsMultipleSelection` (on the collectionview - which you set to `false`) and then you have `indexPathsForSelectedItems` (also on the collectionview) and `isSelected` & `isHighlighted` on the cells, which you can override and implement any customisations.

Comment: @Alladinian could you give a practical example through my code? to understand how you would implement your suggestion?

Comment: I guess something along these lines: Your `selectedIndex` is replaced with `[[collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] firstObject]` (be careful, it can be `nil`), `didSelect` keeps just the scrolling logic and finally your custom cell classes override `selected` and/or `highlighted` and do whatever you do in `highlightYear` in your current code. I hope that this makes sense...